# What form of energy is magnetism stored in?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

In physics class I was told that there are 9 forms of energy:

-Electrical

-Light

-Thermal

-Nuclear

-Elastic Potential

-Gravitational Potential

-Sound

-Kinetic

-Chemical

So, my question is, what form of energy is the energy stored in when two magnets are pulled apart?

Comment: What is "sound" energy? I would consider that the same as kinetic and the same in any other form of wave.

Comment: Did you ask your teacher what is special about those nine categories? Did you ask where the list came from?

Comment: Does "electrical" refer to the energy that can be stored in a capacitor?  to the energy that can be stored in an inductor?  To the energy that can be stored in a battery?  To the energy that a battery or a generator can deliver to a resistor?  To all of the above?  They're all different phenomena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** **Electrical (or electromagnetic)**

The formula of the energy in magnetic fields can be written in two forms, as follows,

$$
W=\frac{1}{2}\int_V(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{J})d\tau \ ,
$$
and

$$
W=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\int_{all\  space}B^2d\tau\ ,
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential, $\mathbf{J}$ is the volume current density, and $B$ is the magnitude of the magnetic field.

So, we can say the energy is stored in the magnetic field, in the amount $B^2/2\mu_0$ per unit volume. And we can also say that the energy is stored in the current distribution in the amount $\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{J})$ per unit volume.

I recommend Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* for you, and you can read it to get more details.